# How do I display Angular UI Bootstrap date picker on click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have an Angular app that uses Full Calendar. I have a [Full Calendar custom button](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/) that when a user clicks, should open a [Angular Bootstrap Datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker). I'm currently toggling CSS visibility but for some reason, the date picker doesn't display (after clicking the button) unless I resize the window.

My template:

```
<div id="cal-go-to-date" ng-style="goToDate.style">
  <div uib-datepicker ng-model="goToDate.dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="goToDate.options"></div>
</div>
```

My Angular controller:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar: {
    // Other configuration
    header: {
      center: 'title'
    },
    customButtons: {
      goToDate: {
        text: 'go to date',
        click: function(event) {
          $scope.goToDate.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      }
    },
    // Other configuration
  }
};

$scope.goToDate = {
    dt: new Date(),
    options: {
      datepickerMode: 'month',
      minMode: 'month'
    },
    style: {
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': '224px',
      'left': '76px',
      'min-height': '290px',
      'z-index': '99999',
      'visibility': 'hidden'
    }
  };
```

I am calling `$scope.goToDate.style.visibility = 'visible';` but that doesn't work unless I resize the window. What can I do to toggle the visibility of the picker?

Comment: That sounds like it's happening outside the scope, since a resize will make it take effect.  Can you post the code showing how and when you change the visibility property?

Comment: @Archer I updated the question. See the `click` function inside uiConfig.

Comment: Why not using [`uib-datepicker-popup `](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#datepickerPopup)? Or at least try wrapping the call with [`$applyAsync`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync) like, `$scope.$applyAsync(function(){ $scope.goToDate.style.visibility = 'visible'; });`, since it looks like this happens outside of angularjs scope.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash I am triggering this on clicking a button. uib-datepicker-popup works only on an input field and I don't need one in the UI. I did try using it but it introduced other UI bugs and stuff.

Comment: @Nag see updated comment :)

Comment: @StanislavKvitash You had the right answer! Will mark as "answer" if you move it from a comment to answer. Thank you! Also, any suggestion on how I can hide on clicking anywhere outside?

Comment: @Nag added as answer. One way of achieve hiding - is to put a transparent element "under" the datepicker container and listen to the click event on it. Or some other approaches could be found there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the call with [`$applyAsync`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24applyAsync) like:

```
$scope.$applyAsync(function(){ $scope.goToDate.style.visibility = 'visible'; });
```

since it looks like this happens outside of angularjs scope.

Answer (score 1):

If its the problem resizing try using this function

```
$scope.windowResize = function () {
            setTimeout("$(window).trigger('resize')",400);
         };
```

and then call this function on the click of that button . 
Hope it might help